# How can I make the main panel in shiny occupy the entire width of the screen

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am making an app in shiny and I want the main panel to occupy 100% of the screen, how can I achieve this? In this occasion I am showing a table but I would also like to add a graph so that it can be seen large.

Below I show the code I am using

[screen shiny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGr4C.png)

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Company-Feature Chart"),
    
    
    
    mainPanel(
        uiOutput("seleccione_col1"),
        uiOutput("seleccione_col2"),
        DT::dataTableOutput(outputId =
                                "diagram")
    )
)
)



shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    
    datachart <- read.csv("examplechart1.csv", row.names=1, sep=";")
    
    output$seleccione_col1<- renderUI({
         selectInput(inputId="columnaD", (("Product")), 
                    choices  =names(datachart),
                    selected = names(datachart)[c(1,2)],multiple = TRUE)
    })
    
    output$seleccione_col2<- renderUI({
        
        
        selectInput(inputId="columnaE", (("Features")), 
                    choices  =row.names(datachart),
                    selected = row.names(datachart)[1],multiple = TRUE)
    })
    
 
    output$diagram<- renderDataTable({
        req(input$columnaE)
        
        data  <-datachart[input$columnaE,input$columnaD]

        DT::datatable(data, escape = FALSE,options = list(sDom  = '<"top">lrt<"bottom">ip',lengthChange = FALSE))
    },  rownames = TRUE)
    
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `width` option:

```
mainPanel(
    uiOutput("seleccione_col1"),
    uiOutput("seleccione_col2"),
    DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "diagram"),
    width = 12
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, I'm already learning to control the layout